# 70s book/short story, Man wakes up from suspend animation or cryo and world has collapsed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic, suspended-animation

In the book, the protagonist wakes up from either suspended animation or cryo (Probably supposed to be a short test), After 10-20 years have passed.

He finds the facility abandoned (and looted?), gets to the surface and it looks like a war zone. Wreckage everywhere, smashed buildings, bullet holes everywhere. (I think he gets some gear from the facility, MREs, Water, First Aid kit, Weapons) and goes exploring to find out what happened.

He comes across a (young kid?) who is terrified of him, (maybe trapped or pinned under debris), gives him food and water and digs him out or helps him so the kid trusts him. Eventually the kid leads him to his family (mother & other siblings) who are equally terrified when they see him, but the kid convinces them the protagonist is OK, that he saved his life.

None of the children are really old enough to remember anything from before the protagonist enter the cryo test, but the mother is. He starts questioning her about what happened while he was asleep. She tells him it was NOT another country invading, it was all internal (society collapsed, food shortages, massive riots).

Later, I think they hear a large group of people approaching the (town? city? area?) where the family has been living, and the family becomes frightened again, saying the enemy is coming back.

He says he will help defend them and asks what the enemy looks like. She looks at him and says "They look just like you." He is African American, the implication being that African-American uprisings are what caused the riots and collapse of society.

This might have been a short story/novella. It probably was a paperback in English published in the USA.

I may be misremembering, maybe she did not tell him they look like you, he just went and got into a position to defend against the enemy, and when they approached, realized they were all African-American.

Comment: This is somewhat reminiscent of "The Year of the Quiet Sun" but it's a time machine instead of suspended animation. The near-future race war in the USA matches.

Comment: Your right it is very close. But I don't think its the book I was thinking of. In "tYotQS" when the woman tells him everyone is afraid of black men, he hardly reacts to it. (Cause he still thinks he will go back to his own time soon)  I am sure in the book I was thinking of, it was a big shock to the protagonist when he found out why everyone was afraid of him.

Comment: Sounds very similar to the starting scenario of the RPG - Aftermath! addon - Operation Morphus:

Operation Morpheus is designed as a campaign introduction to an Aftermath! world. The setting is a major university in an important city. The players take the parts of people having volunteered to take part in a ‘short-term’ experiment in cryogenic suspension, only to awaken many long years after the planned time. They find the world in ruins and have no idea of the cause of, reans for, or history of this disaster. Naked and unarmed, they must face a strange new world.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I vote for your proposition. Except for suspended animation it all adds up. And description of the device to travel in time, in the book, can be misleading. I will lay this on OP misremembering some details. I red the book, pretty sure this is it. Otherwise plagiarism...

Comment: @AcePL Your probably right, I maybe miss remembering tYotQS.

Comment: I wonder if this is one of Octavia Butler’s novels? Or a confused misremembering, perhaps of the Clay’s Ark series?